# question body doesn't meet quality standards - how to solve?

Tags: support, question-quality

I try to ask below question, however however I rephrase it I keep getting "doesn't meet our quality standards" error. How I can resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: try enclosing the email address in backticks, cf. https://superuser.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You can only just indicate you want to give access to a specific user group, what that user group is exactly, isn’t relevant to the question